# which way to implement in app billing?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

After reading the android documentation on their developer website,
I've realized that there are two ways to set up a purchase:

1. create an IabHelper instance with a base64 string and use it to request some purchase... in no way it mentions that I have to use a ServiceConnection to bind the the `IInAppBillingService` for Android.
2. There seems to be another way where you have to create a `ServiceConnection` that binds to the `IInAppBillingService`, where you have to create a Bundle etc.

Is it possible to use only the way where I just create the `IabHelper`instance and call the methods on this instance that were acquired from the trivialDrive app ?

Answer (score 1):

IABHelper internally uses ServiceConnection and binds to the service when you startSetup() on IABHelper. As docs state (http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html), you still have to to include the .aidl file in your project for IInAppBillingService.

I strongly suggest to look for alternatives for IABHelper. Many developers (myself included) have found numerous bugs in its implementation. For example, the queryInventoryAsync implementation does not handle concurrency correctly. You will get a lot of crashes due to IABHelper if you use it.

There are numerous alternatives on GitHub.

Comment: Any of those alternatives to IABHelper have a blog or other documentation for implementing them?  Just curious in case I decide latre to switch from IABHelper.

Comment: @joshgoldeneagle: You could take look at https://github.com/serso/android-checkout

Answer (score 0):

If you take a closer look at the Trivial Drive and its IabHelper class as described in [Selling In-app Products](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/index.html) you will notice that it indeed uses a ServiceConnection. I would recommend you to use the IabHelper, since it provides all boilerplate code you will need. Read up on the provided documentation though, especially the parts concerning security.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at IabHelper class, you can see it contains every single pieces of code from [Implementing In-App Billing](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html) tutorial.

So, [Preparing Your In-app Billing Application](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html) provide a set of classes (IabHelper) that convenient for you to use In-App Billing v3.

Well, In my opinion, we should use IabHelper to get the best practice for the In-App Billing implementation. You also can write your own class in cáe of you need some extra purpose for the project.